# Read from a file ints and floats to store them in a two dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, file-processing

I want to read from a file ints and floats, and then I want to store them in a two dimensional array.

Let say I have a file with two columns. First column integers, and second column floats. Let say I have a 20 row

define SIZE 100 //100 entries (100lines on a file)

define SENSORN 10

This is my code:

```
FILE *fptr;
char filename[100];

char dummy1[1];//dummy character that help me to erase what is the buffer when using gets()
int numberOfSensors;
int time[SENSORN][SIZE];
float powerConsumption[SENSORN][SIZE];

int sensor_num;
int count1 = 0;

printf("Please enter the number of sensors: ");
scanf("%d", &numberOfSensors);

//Asking for the link 
//numberOfSensors - 1 because for example, if we want only 2 sensors we need sensor0 and sensor1 only
for (sensor_num = 0; sensor_num <= (numberOfSensors - 1); sensor_num++)
{
    printf("Please enter the file location for sensor %d\n", sensor_num);
    printf("NOTE: use double backslashes to enter file location \n");

    gets(dummy1);//clearing the buffer
    gets(filename);

    fptr = fopen(filename, "r");

    //if file cannot be opened, then display and error message
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening the file! %s \n", filename);
        printf("Please restart the program \n");
        return 0; //exit the program
    }

    else
    {
        //Loop that let us read and print all the file by storing each value to its respective array
        while (!feof(fptr))
        {
            //storing all the values in their respective array
            //sensor_num is the sensor number
            //count1 is the line number we are reading from the file
            fscanf(fptr, "%d %f", &time[sensor_num][count1], &powerConsumption[sensor_num][count1]);

            //making sure we have all the values stored
            //Note: do not comment the following line in order to check that all values are stored
            fprintf(stdout, "%d %6.2f \n", time[sensor_num][count1], powerConsumption[sensor_num][count1]);
            count1++;
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like it is reading my file, but when I debug it only stores garbage on my arrays. Can somebody explains me what is wrong with this?

Thank you so much! :D

Comment: `while (!feof(fptr))` is wrong, rather `while (fscanf(fptr, "%d %f", &time[sensor_num][count1], &powerConsumption[sensor_num][count1]) == 2)`

Comment: 1) Posting examples of the file would help.  2) Post definition of `SENSORN`, `SIZE`.

Comment: #define SIZE 100 //100 entries (100lines on a file)
#define SENSORN 10

Comment: The first suggestion is to check that fscanf returns 2 (really reads two fields as you wish). It should be true until feof(fptr) flagged; otherwise your input doesn't comply the format.

Comment: Thank you! 
That helped me!